# data.table replacing a value by NA

Tags: r, data.table

I want to replace `0` by `NA` in each column of a `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(V1=0:2, V2=2:0)
dt1

   V1 V2
1:  0  2
2:  1  1
3:  2  0

dt1==0
       V1    V2
[1,]  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
```

I tried this one

```
dt1[dt1==0] 
Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, dt1 == 0) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #1611.
```

And also tried this one

```
dt1[dt1==0, .SD :=NA]
```

**Edited**

Partial `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

data.table_1.9.4
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try `set` for multiple columns.  It will be faster as the overhead of `.[data.table` is avoided

```
for(j in seq_along(dt1)){
         set(dt1, i=which(dt1[[j]]==0), j=j, value=NA)
}
dt1
#   V1 V2
#1: NA  2
#2:  1  1
#3:  2 NA
```

Or another option would be looping with `lapply` and then change the `0` values to NA with `replace`

```
dt1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, which(x==0), NA))]
```

Or we can make use of some arthithmetic operations to convert the 0 value to NA.

```
 dt1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) (NA^!x) *x)]
```

The way `(NA^!x)*x` this works is by converting the `!x` i.e. a logical TRUE/FALSE vector for each column (where TRUE corresponds to 0 value) to `NA` and 1 by doing `NA^!x`.  We multiply with the x value to replace the 1 with the x value corresponding to it while the NA will remain as such.

Or a syntax similar to `base R` would be

```
  is.na(dt1) <- dt1==0
```

But this method may not be that efficient for large data.table as `dt1==0` would be a logical matrix and also as @Roland mentioned in the comments that the dataset would be copied.  I would either use the `lapply` based or the more efficient `set` for larger datasets.

Comment: you need to add gc() to the loop if you have a large matrix and want to avoid your mem use to explode.

Answer (score 3):

`dt1[dt1==0] <- NA` worked for me.

```
dt1[dt1==0] <- NA
dt1
##   V1 V2
##1: NA  2
##2:  1  1
##3:  2 NA
```

As noted by Roland, this does make a copy of the `data.table` object, and will be slower.

Comment: I was doing the same way but getting error for `dt1[dt1==0]`.

Comment: This is not working for me. Don't know why?

Comment: Don't do this. It copies the whole data.table, which is slow when it's of decent size.

Comment: @Roland thanks, good to know!